# What happens with a component that is inside of a lazy loaded component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

Let's suppose that I have a component that lazy loads (ComponentA), and inside of that component I import a component without lazy loading (ComponentB). Do the componentB lazy loads too?

```
import ComponentA from 'componentA/loadable';


export default App = () => {
return <ComponentA />;
}
```

**ComponentA.js**

```
import ComponentB from '../ComponentB'

export default ComponentA = () => <ComponentB />;
```

PS: My English skills aren't good enough, but I hope you understand my question.

Comment: they load when they are told to load. so if you implemented lazy loading for the child components they will also be lazy loaded. otherwise they will load once the main component loads.

Comment: @cloned I think I didn't say it right, so I edited the question, I mean I think you mean about importing the two components in the same file and putting as a children a component that doesn't lazy loads